# Interaction to show/hide tags using info icon

Tags: gui-design, responsive-design, mobile-web, tags, tagging

**Product :** Universal file holder for a large enterprise

**Situation :** Navigation side bar with unnecessary file details

The files are tagged so they can be filtered.  However, we already have those as filter options. The picture below shows how the tags eat up a lot of vertical space.
[image]

The stakeholders are unsure about their importance right now. And to be honest, user testing suggests that they are in a kind of blind spot, so I would like to hide them to begin with. So, hiding them under an info icon does not seem to be an outrageous idea.

[image]

However, now I'm unsure about the interaction. S**hould I show and hide at the exact spot? They could show up on hover on desktop (Desktop view below) but how would I show them on mobile?**

Comment: What happens when the user clicks on the arrow? What happens when the user clicks on "...more"? What happens if the user taps the title/whole area of the file? Can you show the clickable regions?

Comment: Thanks to Apple, you can now do the Hover mechanism using 3D touch on iPhone devices. I think for your example, this might be the perfect use-case to use 3D touch for more info. http://www.apple.com/in/iphone-6s/3d-touch/

Comment: @BernardoDoré the arrow is share icon which will open a modal view to search for a user and then share with him. Clicking on more shows the description online. The file will open if you click on the entire file..

Comment: I'd like to know what will be the correct way to hide the tags. What should be the interaction there ?

Comment: In order to give you my informed opinion I need to understand better the interactive elements you are trying to accommodate. That's why I asked.
What is the primary action? Share, open or more? By primary I mean the most commonly used, so logically, the one you want to facilitate. File info seems like a secondary action so based on the primary we can discuss further. How do you rank the frequency of each action or the importance of each design element in the space (interactive or not)? Is this an app or responsive/adaptive website? The primary actions may differ based on context.

Comment: So imagine pre defined folders in google drive that contain files added by your class admin. Each file are related to some other subject and they are shown via tags. The tags right now are static and do nothing. Also user test suggest, user are not even looking at them. So I want to hide them.

The arrow icon : Opens share to add user
The more : Show and hide file description 

I wish to add an info icon to hide the tags. Is this the right way ? if yes, should I show the tags in a modal window.
or a smal divs poping out like a tongue from in the "info" icon.

Comment: Sry I was editing with some more points. I understand the tags. Keep going.

Comment: The Primary action would be clicking on the file name to access it. We don't have analystics to suggest if Share or tags will be used as much as we predict.

This can be accessed on all 3 view. Desktop, Mobile and Tablet. The page shows up with a web view.

Comment: If there is no interaction in the tags I'd show them after the user clicks on "more". The "i" icon gives too much importance imho.

You can also use the "i" icon and put everything in there, the description and the tags. This will save you some more vertical space.

Comment: I like your suggestion to add the tags under the more.. But, the more is nothing but concatenated description. The description is not mandatory and could might as well be a single word. In which case there will be no "more" . WWhat ahppesn to the tags then ?

Comment: If there is a description and/or tags, the "more" is there. Otherwise there is no "more".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41113/discussion-between-nodnin-and-bernardo-dore).

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned previously, the info tag is misleading. However, I think you were close to your solution with the "...more" option. This option could not only reveal the rest of the description, but also the tags. Like follows:

**Default View**

[image: Step 1]

**Detailed View (after tapping "...more")**

[image: Step 2]

Also, "...more" could be replaced with "Details" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The "i" icon is not referencing tags. It might be better to use the word "tag" (doesn't take much more space then i but has a clear function) to show/hide the tags.